# Como colocar o RSS Feed ao lado da Google Map API

Tags: html, css, rss

Bom dia,
Estou a tentar fazer uma pequena página em HTML com uma API da Google Maps e de um RSS feed.
No entanto, não estou a conseguir colocar o meu RSS feed no lado direito da API. Alguém me consegue ajudar?

Aqui está o exemplo da minha página:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
Aqui está o código referente ao RSS Feed:

```
<div id="widgetmain" style="text-align:left;overflow-y:auto;overflow-x:hidden;width:200px;background-color:#transparent; border:1px solid #333333;">
    <div id="rsswidget" style="height:500px;">
        <iframe src="http://us1.rssfeedwidget.com/getrss.php?time=1495402870570&amp;x=http%3A%2F%2Ffeeds.feedburner.com%2Fthr%2Freviews%2Fallreviews&amp;w=200&amp;h=500&amp;bc=333333&amp;bw=1&amp;bgc=transparent&amp;m=10&amp;it=true&amp;t=(default)&amp;tc=333333&amp;ts=15&amp;tb=transparent&amp;il=true&amp;lc=000003&amp;ls=14&amp;lb=true&amp;id=false&amp;dc=333333&amp;ds=14&amp;idt=true&amp;dtc=000000&amp;dts=12" border="0" hspace="0" vspace="0" frameborder="no" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" style="border:0; padding:0; margin:0; width:200px; height:500px;" id="rssOutput">Reading RSS Feed ...
        </iframe>
    </div>
    <div style="text-align:right;margin-bottom:0;border-top:1px solid #333333;" id="widgetbottom">
        <span style="font-size:70%"><a href="http://www.rssfeedwidget.com">RSS feed</a>&nbsp;</span>
        <br>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Entretanto, já resolvi a dúvida. Caso alguém tenha a mesma dúvida que eu, aqui fica a solução:
No div do feed incluí  float: right ;
No style do mapa, incluí display:inline-block;

Comment: ou você pode criar um section position absolute left paea o rss e um position absolute right para o map